# That was not the right table: Access wiped the wrong data

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I... don't quite know if I have the right idea about Access here.

I wrote the following, to grab some data that existed in two places:-

```
Select TableOne.*
from TableOne inner join TableTwo
on  TableOne.[LINK] = TableTwo.[LINK]
```

Now, my interpretation of this is:

- Find the table "TableOne"
- Match the `LINK` field to the corresponding field in the table "TableTwo"
- Show only records from TableOne *that have a matching record in TableTwo*

Just to make sure, I ran the query with some sample tables in SSMS, and it worked as expected.

So why, when I deleted the rows from within that query, did it delete the rows from TableTwo, and *NOT* from TableOne as expected? I've just lost ~3 days of work.

Edit: For clarity, I manually selected the rows in the query window and deleted them. I did not use a delete query - I've been stung by that a couple of times lately.

Comment: Could you include you delete statement?

Comment: What was your DELETE Query? Did you have the relationship defined in the Relationship window between these two tables?

Comment: @parakmiakos Edited. I didn't use a query.

Comment: Perhaps you've set up your relationships to cascade delete in the relationships window?

Comment: @JenZzz I actually haven't set up any relationships at all, I've just been specifying links in queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have deleted the records manually, your query has to be updateable. This means that your query couldn't have been solely a cartesian join or a join without referential integrity, since these queries are non-updateable in ms access.

When I recreate your query based on two fields without indexes or primary keys, I am not even able to manualy delete records. This leads me to believe there was unknowingly a relationship established which deleted the records in table two. Perhaps you should take a look in the design view of your queries and relationships window, since the query itself should indeed select only records from table one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it got deleted, but I suggest to rewrite your query:

```
delete TableOne
where  LINK in (select LINK from TableTwo)
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I'm already aware of how to do so. I'm just confused as to why the displayed data was shown from TableTwo.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
DELETE TableOne 
    FROM TableOne a
    INNER JOIN
    TableTwo b on b.Bid = a.Bid
    and [my filter condition]
```